# Cycle detection in unweighted graph by shortest path algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, shortest-path

How can I find cycle in unweighted graph by shortest path algorithm in python?
I want to find shortest path from a node to itself, my data networks is undirected and without weight. Could anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried something yet ?

Comment: Do proper research before asking a question this is too broad for anyone to help you. What to you mean by shortest path algorithm? Dijkstra's algorithm? You can try checking depth first search if you care only for cycle detection (can't be used for shortest path). If an unexplored edge leads to already visited node then you found a cycle.

Comment: Dijkstra's or primal algorithm.